# Rendering a partial view to a string by calling an action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have been experimenting with rendering an view to a string using methods outlines here:

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

The issue is that I need to call my controller action which does not happen when calling View.Render.

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
```

My question is, how can I call RenderAction on an arbitrary controller passing in a route? I am trying to composite together the results of a number of partial views into a single result which will get passed back to the browser.

My code so far. Works except that the action method is not called.

```
    public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }



        var route = new RouteData();
        route.Values.Add("controller", "Test1");
        route.Values.Add("action", "Index");

        var controller1 = new Test1Controller();

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext, route), controller1);
        controller1.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
        var viewString = controller1.RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/Test1/Index.cshtml", (object)model);
```

My goal is to create a simple CMS system that composites together the results of a number of controller actions/views and outputs them into a layout.

I have a primary controller action that retrieves a page description from the database. The code loops over a list of other controllers and calls their actions which results in a dynamic object model and a list of partial html snippets that is handed off to a custom WebViewPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat unsure of what you're trying to accomplish. However, that aside `RenderPartialViewToString` is an extension method. To use within a controller action you could do something as simple as this:

```
var result = this.RenderPartialViewToString("Index", model)
```

Where model is the strongly typed model used within the "Index" view. If for example you were wanting to render a view to string to use within a JSON action you could return a JSONResult with:

```
return new JsonResult
           {
               JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
               Data = new {html = this.RenderPartialViewToString("Index", model)}
           };
```

Comment: This method only works under the current controller's context. When I create a fake context and call the code, it does not call the controller's action. It only renders the view.

Comment: @rboarman is your question about unit testing a controller action that makes use of renderpartialviewtostring?